# Flutter UI Create menu with function after click icon more

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ui

Halo,

First, I wanna show you my current UI :

[image]

And here's the code for red circle function :

```
InkWell(
  onTap: null,
  child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz,
    size: 18,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
  ),
),
```

What action I needed is to show pop-up menu like this after click the icon, for example :

[image]

I need that to create edit and delete with function to navigate to another page, and need to know how to control menu position.

I already check on pub.dev, but it didn't resolve my problem.
Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: You want to second image like alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :
the package is here : **https://pub.dev/packages/pull_down_button**

```
PullDownButton(
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    PullDownMenuItem(
      title: 'Menu item',
      onTap: () => action(),
    ),
    const PullDownMenuDivider(),
    PullDownMenuItem(
      title: 'Menu item 2',
      onTap: () => action2(),
    ),
  ],
  position: PullDownMenuPosition.under,
  buttonBuilder: (context, showMenu) => CupertinoButton(
    onPressed: showMenu,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle),
  ),
);
```

result :
[image]

Comment: can I ask you, how to made this icon before text. This widget is hard to customize

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `PopupMenuButton` you can find here an [example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. and used [PopupMenuButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)

Declare Key Variable:

```
  final GlobalKey menuKey = GlobalKey();
```

Widget:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    dynamic state = menuKey.currentState;
    state.showButtonMenu();
  },
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    key: menuKey,
    itemBuilder: (_) => const <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text('Show Test'),
        value: 'Test',
      ),
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text('Edit Test Solution'),
        value: 'Edit',
      ),
    ],
    onSelected: (_) {},
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]